# Is it possible to update an already open document in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In JS, Is there a better way of doing the following:

I'm finding a user, and then checking password, then I wish to update the same users' document.

Can I leverage the already open document (var doc) for updating? Or do as the code below does and re-search for name:name when updating.

```
user_collection.findOne({ name:name }, function(err, doc) {
    if(err) 
        throw err;
    if(doc) {
        // verify doc.password etc
        user_collection.update({ name:name }, {$set: { last_joined:last_joined }}, { upsert:true }, function(err, doc) {
            if(err) {  
                // log error 
            }
        });                 
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "already open document"? There is no such thing. And yes, you have to search every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - use the [`save`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) method.

The document you have in `doc` is an in-memory copy of the record in the database. If you want to modify it then save it to the database, you need to either use the `update` method as you do, or use `save(modified_doc)`.

Note: as freakish said, you probably should use `user_collection.update({ _id: doc._id }, ...)` instead of searching for `name` again, since it may not be unique.

Comment: Save is essentially the same as updating based on `_id`. Assuming that there is an index on `name` it will not give any performance boost. If that is what OP's looking for. If it is only to shorten the code, then yes, it will shorten the code. However it has to be noted that there is a difference in functionality. If `name` is not unique then two operations will obviously behave differently. Also there is a problem if he accidentaly modifies one of the fields. With `$set` you can be sure that only specified fields will get updated.

Comment: @Freakish okay so the fastest and safest is to change the update code from {name:name} to {_id:doc._id}? Sounds good to me! - Thanks

Comment: @user975033 Not necessarily fastest (equally fast), but definitely safest.